# javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to rename the id attribute of an element using jQuery. I need to match the following:

- row_1
- row_2
- row_xx etc

this is what i have so far:

```
$('.form .newsCategories .row .itemWrap .itemTop .inputBtn').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id").replace($(this).attr("id").match(/\[row_[0-9]+\]/), "roww_"+index));
    });
```

but this fails. my reg ex is faulty i think. please help
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding the resulting IDs you want, you can just do this:

```
this.id = "row" + index;
```

E.g., if you want to find all of them and renumber them in document order:

```
$("*[id^=row]").each(function(index) {
    this.id = "row" + index;
});
```

That uses an [attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (`^=`) to find only elements whose `id` starts with "row", and then renumbers them in document order.

---

**Off-topic**: Note that there's no reason at all to use `$(this).attr("id")`; the DOM element itself has an `id` property which reflects the `id` attribute directly.

Comment: +1 Yes the OP seems to be doing a hell of a lot with attr("id") unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra set of square ([ ]) brackets. Change it to:

```
/row_[0-9]+/
```

or equivalent:

```
/row_\d+/
```

Comment: @Shane Km I would look at TJ Crowder's answer, you seem to be doing too much to simply rename the `id` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Using the `[]`s creates a character class which you do not need to do. Try this regex...

`/row_[0-9]+/`